# Asking fine location permission

Tags: android, permissions, location

I want to access fine location from within my app and, for this, I declare an `ActivityResultLauncher`with :

```
    protected final ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> l = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), isGranted -> {
    if (isGranted .get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) & isGranted .get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, positionChangesListener);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getText(R.string.PermissionNotAllowed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        finish();
    }
});
```

When I want to ask for this permission, I use :

```
l.launch(new String [] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION});
```

Unfortunately, the panel asking the user to grant permission doesn't show up. This doesn't prevent the callback from being executed, but with permissions denied. My app then immediatly stops, informing the user it can't continue to work if fine location permission isn't granted.

Any idea which could solve my problem?

Comment: Please read it : 
https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions

Comment: Already read. Doing exactly as said in this tutorial, as you can verify with the code I posted, but the window asking for permission doesn't show up. Nevertheless, the `ActivityResultLauncher` is started, but with both permissions denied.

Comment: The problem has disappeared, but I don't know why...

Comment: Take the permisions one by one and try them

Answer (score 0):

wait where are asking for permission shouldn't it be in else ? after that have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`
in your manifest

Comment: Both permissions are declared in the Manifest file. Don't understand your question...

Comment: My question is the `else` block is calling a `toast` and `finish` you should be asking for permission inside this `else `  block i see you said problem is disappeared have you solved it ?

Comment: I'm asking for permissions long before the `else`. That's why the `ActivityResultLanuncher` is launched. And yes, the problem is solved, but I can't say why.